# When building deb files using dpkg, I can't get it to ignore hidden files such as .git and .gitignore

Tags: ubuntu, package, debian, deb

I have a pretty simple project for an internal package at my company. I've got a base directory with DEBIAN, etc and opt in it with the files I need to package and install.

I go up one directory and run the following to create my package:

```
dpkg -b myproject myproject_1.0_all.deb
```

However, the resulting .deb file has all my .gitignore files and the base .git file. Is there any way to prevent dpkg from including hidden files in to the finished .deb?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing my package root in a subdirectory and creating a build script at the root that created all the empty directories I needed, so I wouldn't need .gitignore files and the .git file would no longer get packaged.